# When should you use Azure Ad B2C

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Is there something you cannot do with Azure Ad in which case you would use Azure Ad B2C?

Comment: Hi, if the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions

Answer (score 2):

Azure AD now allows social logins via [external identities](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory/external-identities/).

Azure AD is typically for corporate customers that are mainly domain-joined e.g. email is joe@company.co.nz.

Azure AD B2C is for a non-corporate customer - not domain-joined e.g. email is joe@some-smtp.co.nz.

B2C also caters for people that don't have an email address e.g. via phone with an OTP.

Answer (score 1):

One of the best use case of using Azure AD B2C is it allow users to sign in to your application with credentials from external social or enterprise identity providers (IdP). Azure AD B2C supports external identity providers like Facebook, Microsoft account, Google, Twitter, and any identity provider that supports OAuth 1.0, OAuth 2.0, OpenID Connect, and SAML protocols.
With external identity provider federation, you can offer your consumers the ability to sign in with their existing social or enterprise accounts, without having to create a new account just for your application.

Please refer these [documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/technical-overview) for more information. 
Regarding technical comparisons between Azure ad b2b and azure ad b2c please refer [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/compare-with-b2c)

Comment: Agree @Raghavendra, that is the only advantage right? Using external identities and managing user flows out of the box

Comment: Have a look at these examples of what you can do with Identity Experience Framework: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples

Answer (score 1):

It’s very dependent on your user base. If you are serving an enterprise audience you would not use B2C but many public facing apps do not need you to login with your organisational email. Is there a use case that you have in mind, might be a good discussion if you do?

Comment: Agreed - use case is key.